# IText table.deleteBodyRow() within rowspans causes error

Tags: java, itext

I am trying to create a table with rigthmost column is spanning multiple rows

I achieve this with the `cell.setRowspan(numOfRows);`

I have to show the sum of some column values at the end of the pages. For that purpose, I create a page event and print current total values to the footer when those events fired. In order to get the right total sum at the page end, I call the following code block after each row.

```
table.addCell(...)
....
document.add(table);
table.deleteBodyRows();
....
```

By this way, if page end is reached, it'll fire an event and I can write the correct sum value to the footer.

The problem is that when I call `table.deleteBodyRows()` within a row span, the code gives  `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`

I couldn't find any solution to this problem. Is there something that I missed or is there any other way to achieve this requirement???

---

Here is an example code block (some bigger than SSCCE):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int totalSum = 0;
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("c:/sample.pdf"));
    document.open();

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
    table.setWidths(new int[]{1,1,1});
    table.setTotalWidth(document.right() - document.left());
    table.setLockedWidth(true);
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        table.getDefaultCell().setRowspan(20);
        table.addCell(new Phrase("Spanning Row : "+j));
        table.getDefaultCell().setRowspan(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            table.addCell(new Phrase("Row Num : "+i));  
            table.addCell(new Phrase("Blah blah..."));
            document.add(table);
            table.deleteBodyRows();
            totalSum += i;  // if the page break occures i'll write current totalSum to the footer
        }
    }
    document.add(table);

    document.close();
}
```

I just want to write the content of the table after each row in order to understand the page end...

Comment: Which version of iText are you using? Plenty of fixes have been applied in the most recent releases.

Comment: I was using itextpdf-5.1.3.jar. After your comment i changed it to latest 5.4.4 but still failing... I post here because i can't decide whether it is a bug or not. Since I am using row span and want to divide that spanning row to the two page.

Comment: Can you provide a SSCCE? http://sscce.org

Comment: I've modified the content with an example

Comment: While I was preparing some example I realized that the problem is not related with page break but the statement : `table.deleteBodyRows();`. I modified the question and title accordingly...